# Save and load Generic class

Tags: java

Generic class

```
package shopmanager;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Linh
 */
public class Warehouse<T> {

    private List<T> Product;

    public void output() {

        if (Product != null && !Product.isEmpty()) {
            List<T> c;
            for (int i = 0; i < Product.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(Product.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    public void add(List<T> Product) {
        this.Product = Product;
        try {
            save();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Warehouse.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public List<T> getProduct() {
        if (Product == null) {
            Product = new ArrayList<T>();
        }
        return this.Product;
    }

    public void save() throws IOException{
            FileOutputStream fs=new FileOutputStream("obj.dat");
            ObjectOutputStream os=new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
            os.writeObject(Product);
            fs.close();
            os.close();
    }
}
```

How do I save and load Generic class into a file

Comment: Please stick to Java naming conventions and do not use capital letters at the start of variable names.
To answer a part of your question: If you want to write the plain objects to a file like you are trying to do, make sure all Objects implement the Serializable marker interface.

Comment: i have 4 class extern Product i don't now how to write all in one file

Answer (score 0):

serialization is the process to store the object into persistent storage area (file...etc) and by using the de-serialization we can restore the object from file

implements java.io.Serializable

please check
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Comment: i try using this but i can write only one obj